# Calculate R+ RC to stretch pulse from hall effect output

Tags: remote-control, pulse

I have a [Optek OH090U](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbzfq.png) hall-effect.

I am trying to stretch a pulsed output by adding an RC circuit. Basically I want the output to be on (low) as long as there is a pulsing of the magnetic field and high when not pulsing. The present value for my pull up resistor is 960 ohms (24V/25mA = 960). Which provides the wave shown. My magnetic pulse a 70/30 duty cycle at 10Hz (65ms high, 35ms low). The output is normally high. With no magnetic field (stopped), the output transistor is OFF = +24V (pulled up by pull up resistor). Specs on downstream device's input: Input voltage 4.25-26.4 V Input resistance 5.4 kΩ

I would like to add a parallel RC in series with the pull up as follows:

[image]
[image]
Question: How to calculate R2 & C2 to stretch the 65ms pulse? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "_Basically I want the output to be on (low) as long as there is a pulse and high when not._" Well then you _don't_ want a pulse extender - you just use a pull-up resistor. Please clarify your original post.

Comment: OK, I see the edit and understand. We need to know (1) the threshold (switchover) voltage of the device you are feeding, (2) its input impedance and (3) the maximum input voltage.

Comment: I am somewhat new to this forum. Should I be replying to your comment or adding the reply to original post? Specs on device's input:  
Input voltage 4.25-26.4 V Input resistance 5.4 kΩ

Comment: Best to put all the details in the original question so that anyone else answering has all the details in one place and doesn't have to trawl through the comments. It's a good idea then to notify whoever asked for the additional info in the comments. Pop an @ in front of their name and it will show up in their messages.

Comment: Good work with the schematic but you don't have to screen grab it. Just hit save and it's automatically embedded in your post and, best of all, can be edited later.

Comment: Thanks... Can't save because I don't have an account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an incomplete answer but the thought process may help.

There are very many details left out of your question including

- the threshold (switchover) voltage of the device you are feeding,
- its input impedance
- the maximum input voltage.

But most importantly, you haven't specified whether the device can stop pulsing in the on or off state or if it could be either. This affects the solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYCsov.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Typical PLC interface for current sinking sensor to current sourcing input with C1 providing extended "low" time. The problem with this circuit is that when Q1 turns on the pulse of current from C1 may damage the transistor.*

If this is the situation you are trying to address *and* the sensor stops with Q1 turned off then the solution may be very simple. Q1 will discharge C every time Q1 turns on and will light D1. When Q1 turns off R1 will recharge C and D1 will turn off. Proceed as follows:

- Switch your multimeter to DC mA and measure the current from PLC input to ground. This will tell you the rate that C1 will be charged at. It will also, should you so wish, enable you to calculate the input resistance of the PLC.
- Using the relationship \$ I = C \frac {dv}{dt} \$ we can calculate the capacitor value required to limit the rise of voltage as follows: 
  $$ C = \frac {I} {\frac {dv}{dt}} $$

e.g. We measured the source current as 10 mA and we want the voltage to rise at 5 V / 100 ms then

$$ C = \frac {10m} {\frac {5}{100m}} = \frac {10m \times 100m}{5} = 200~\mu $$

So something about 200 uF would do the trick.

---

Update (after blowing the OP's sensor).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPWYHb.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. (a) R2 will limit the current but will raise the "low" voltage on the PLC input. (b) Moving R2 and addition of D3 solves the problem.*

The problem we have seen with the damaged sensor is that C1 charges up to 24 V and delivers a high current pulse through Q1 when the sensor turns on. To limit the current to < 25 mA we need to add a 1k resistor. If we try this as shown in Figure 2a we will find that the minimum voltage on the PLC input will be about 4 V due to the potential divider effect of R1 and R2. This doesn't give us a robust operating margin and will mess up the capacitor calculations.

Figure 1b addresses this with the addition of D3.

- When Q1 turns on it pulls the PLC input low immediately. The PLC will source \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {22}{5k6} = 4~mA \$ (allowing 2 V for the LED voltage drop).
- It will also discharge C2 through R4. R4 has been increased to 1k2 to reduce the max current from C2 to < 20 mA so that the total through Q1 < 25 mA. \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {24}{20m} = 1k2 \$.
- C2 will discharge by 99% after five RC time constants. For example, with 200 uF  \$ T_{DISC} = 5 \tau = 5 RC = 5 \times 1k2 \times 200u = 1.2~ms \$

Unfortunately this is too long for your application.

In retrospect I suspect a 555-based pulse extender may be a better option. The standard 555 only works up to 15 V. If you use a 12 V Zener diode between the +24 V power rail and the 555 you might be able to keep the component count low.

Comment: I Updated the original post with downstream input device specs.

Comment: Thanks. I think there is enough information in my answer for you to recalculate with your values. Consider my point about the stop condition - on / off / either.

Comment: You are showing the capacitor across the transistor output. Why wouldn't I put it in series with the pull up?

Comment: The pull-up is in the PLC. If you put C in series with the pull-up then no DC can flow. The capacitor will charge once and stay there.

Comment: I have a 960 ohm pull up resistor as recommended by the the hall effect data sheet.

Comment: It's doing nothing except wasting power. All that is required is to light the LED in your PLC. You do this by turning Q1 on. 960 Ω is the minimum value you can use. Any lower and you'll have more than 25 mA running through Q1 and 25 mA, it appears, is the max allowed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Right, I had set it up on a bench beforehand before actually hooking up to my "PLC" input, thus the need for the pull up. So... 0.01/ (24V/0.1) = 41.6 uF ? Is an electrolytic cap ok?

Comment: Electrolytic is fine because the polarity will never reverse. Your calculation isn't right: you've allowed the voltage to change 24 V in 0.1 s. That will allow it to toggle every pulse. You need to keep below 4.25 V to prevent it going high - say 4 V. \$ C = 0.01 / \frac {4}{0.1} = \frac {0.01 \times 0.1}{4} = 250~uF \$. You can go much bigger - it will just take longer to turn off.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did a bench test, i.e. not connected to the PLC input. I tried a 470uF with 16K pull up that I had on hand which was the closest I could find to the 15.4K of the input. That took approx 10 sec to turn off.  250uF was better.  However when I tried a 100uF (to get the turn off time a little smaller) it damaged the hall effect - it no longer turns off.  Shouldn't the pull up have limited the current?

Comment: Sorry for delay. No, the problem is that we haven't limited the current from the charged capacitor to the sensor. When it turns on it rapidly discharges the capacitor the peak current must be too high. I'll update with another suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, but I've failed to give you a good solution to your question. Just wondering, but why aren't you extending the pulse in the PLC code?

Comment: Thanks for the updated diagram & explanation. Makes sense now. I apologize for inappropriately using the term pulse stretch in my original post. I only needed to know that the sensor was pulsing or not. ie PLC sees a high when sensor is pulsing & low when it is not pulsing, or vice versa. I wanted to see if I could do this electronically (without software) to learn what I could learn. I did resort to counting pulses in the PLC code and that seems to be working well. Thanks again for the solution and explanations!  I hope others can benefit from this post as much as I did!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. It is much easier to give a defined timeout in the PLC than with the analog electronics. I would use a pair of one-shots to reset the timer - one on the positive going edge of the input and one on the negative. If no change is detected the timer times out and indicates stop. Don't use this as a "safe-stop" indication however. If you'd like more on that then let me know and what PLC you're using.